# CSS dont apply in component

Tags: html, css, angular

I've created a component to show the notifications but the template notifications default css are not applying to the component

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="ti-bell"></i>
        <p class="notification" style="color:crimson; font-size: 12px; vertical-align:top;"><b>{{totalNotifications}}</b></p>
        <p>Notificações</p>
        <b class="caret"></b>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li *ngFor="let notification of notifications" ><a [routerLink]="['/callInfo']" [queryParams]="{call:notification.call}">{{setName(notification)}}</a></li>
  </ul>
```

in menu

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown" style="margin-top:25px">
                    <notifications-cmp ></notifications-cmp>
                </li>
```

paper-dashboard.css

```
.navbar .navbar-nav > li > a {
  line-height: 1.42857;
  margin: 15px 0px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav > li > a i,
.navbar .navbar-nav > li > a p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav > li > a i {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav > li > a.btn {
  margin: 18px 3px;
  padding: 7px 18px;
}
.navbar .btn {
  margin: 15px 3px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.navbar .btn-simple {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}
```

that's a part of the css that to inline the elements inside the componenet I made the following change adding this line

```
.navbar .navbar-nav > .dropdown > notifications-cmp  > a i,
.navbar .navbar-nav > .dropdown > notifications-cmp  > a p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}
```

If I put it directly into navbar it works perfectly but using the `<notifications-cmp ></notifications-cmp>` does not work

I wanted it to ignore the tag, to fix the css would be very laborious and time-consuming.

thanks for any help

Comment: Please also show your css

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: I want the css to be applied ignoring the tag, I edited with part of the css

Comment: Can't you just do `.navbar .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a i` I mean do you even need all these selectors? `.dropdown-toggle i` or `.navbar .dropdown-toggle i` or even better, add a unique class to `i` and just target it. I am not sure why the selector structure is so complicated

Comment: the css is already done is part of the template I wanted a way to simplify and work as it should but had to do the way you said creating a css unique to the case but some things I had in the notification of the template itself does not work